# Resultset to list

Tags: java, list, jdbc

I want to create a list with my database field values.
There are 2 columns, name and surname.
I want to create a list that stores all names in name column in a field and then add to my DTO.

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes its possible. But what have your tried?

Comment: 1) [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) 2) *"add to my dto."*  What is a 'DTO'?

Comment: @AndrewThompson Data transfer object.. but I'm guessing you knew that? :P

Comment: @LewsTherin  No I honestly didn't, and was too plum lazy to search on it. :P  Thanks for the info.  :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Steps you can follow**: -

- First you need to have a `List<String>` that will store all your names. Declare it like this: -

  ```
  List<String> nameList = new ArrayList<String>();
  ```
- Now, you have all the records fetched and stored in `ResultSet`. So I assume that you can iterate over `ResultSet` and get each `values` from it. You need to use `ResultSet#getString` to fetch the `name`.
- Now, each time you fetch one record, get the `name` field and add it to your list.

  ```
  while(resultSet.next()) {
      nameList.add(resultSet.getString("name"));
  }
  ```
- Now, since you haven't given enough information about your `DTO`, so that part you need to find out, how to add this `ArrayList` to your `DTO`.
- The above `list` only contains `name` and not `surname` as you wanted only `name`. But if you want both, you need to create a custom DTO `(FullName)`, that
  contains `name` and `surname` as fields. And instantiate it from
  every `ResultSet` and add it to the `List<FullName>`

Comment: What i must do is read 2 columns from a table called CUSTOMER.
the column names are NAME and SURNAME.
i must then store this information in my DTO.

Then from my main class i must write the names and surnames to a file in this format:  

Rohit Jain | Brain Agnew | Andrew Thompson

And im still new to java so have no idea how to do this, at the moment it writes to file but like this:  

Rohit, Brain, Andrew | Jain, Agnew, Thompson

How do i resolve this?

Comment: @user1759247 As I said. Create another DTO - `FullName`, which contains two fields - `name` and `surname`. Now, for every ResultSet, you need to create an instance of your `FullName` DTO, and add it to the `List`. And your List will be declared as : - `List<FullName>`

Comment: @user1759247 And then when you fetch data from your `List`, use it like: - `list.get(0).getName() + " " + list.get(0).getSurname()`

Comment: got it working, but it now displays as Rohit Jain, Andrew Thompson etc, how can i replace , with |?

Thank you / Kind Regards

Comment: @user1759247. Also, you can remove your duplicate comment from above. You might have mistakenly duplicated them.

Comment: @user1759247. How are you displaying it?

Answer (score 3):

JDBC unfortunately doesn't offer any ways to conveniently do this in a one-liner. But there are other APIs, such as [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org) (disclaimer: I work for the company behind jOOQ):

```
List<DTO> list =
DSL.using(connection)
   .fetch("SELECT first_name, last_name FROM table")
   .into(DTO.class);
```

Or [Spring JDBC](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data/)

```
List<DTO> list =
new JdbcTemplate(new SingleConnectionDataSource(connection, true))
   .query("SELECT first_name, last_name FROM table", (rs, rowNum) ->
       new DTO(rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2));
```

Or [Apache DbUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbutils/):

```
List<DTO> list =
new QueryRunner()
   .query(connection, 
          "SELECT first_name, last_name FROM table", 
          new ArrayListHandler())
   .stream()
   .map(array -> new DTO((String) array[0], (String) array[1]))
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I've used Java 8 for the Spring JDBC / Apache DbUtils examples, but it can be done with older versions of Java as well.

Answer (score 2):

It is. What have you tried ?

To access the database, you need to [use JDBC](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html) and execute a query, giving you a `ResultSet`.

I would create an class called `FullName` with 2 String fields `name` and `surname`. Just populate these in a loop using

```
rs.getString("NAME");  // column name
rs.getString("SURNAME");
```

e.g.

```
List<FullName> fullnames = new ArrayList<FullName>();
while (rs.next()) {
    fullnames.add(new FullName(rs));
}
```

Note that I'm populating the object via the `ResultSet` object directly. You may choose instead to implement a constructor taking the 2 name fields.

Note also that I'm creating a `Fullname` object. So the firstname/surname are kept separate and you have the freedom to add initials etc. later. You may prefer to rename this `Person` and that will give you the freedom to add additional attributes going forwards.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is:

```
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
         int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();

         ArrayList<String> resultList= new ArrayList<>(columnCount);
         while (rs.next()) {
             int i = 1;
             while(i <= columnCount) {
                 resultList.add(rs.getString(i++));
             }
         }
         return resultList;
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me->

```
private List<Object[]> convertResultsetToObject(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
    List<Object[]> results = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
    int count = 0;
    if(rs != null) {
        ResultSetMetaData rsm = rs.getMetaData();
        count = rsm.getColumnCount();
    }
    while(rs != null && rs.next()) {
        Object [] obj = new Object[count];
        int temp = 1;
        while(temp <= count) {
            obj[temp - 1] = rs.getObject(temp);
            temp++;
        }
        results.add(obj);
    }
    return results;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).