# How to retrieve resultset on JAVA JSP page?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsp

I want to show result set passed from controller to JSP page and I'm using Spring framework.
Anyone have any idea how to display data on my JSP page. I don't have any idea how to display data on table.

Model/ Domain:

```
package com.mycompany.domain;

public class Accounts {

private int accNumber;
private String accName;
private int accBalance;

public Accounts(int accNumber, String accName, int accBalance) {

    this.accNumber = accNumber;
    this.accName = accName;
    this.accBalance = accBalance;
}

public int getAccNumber() {
    return accNumber;
}

public String getAccName() {
    return accName;
}

public int getAccBalance() {
    return accBalance;
}

public void setAccNumber(int accNumber) {
    this.accNumber = accNumber;
}

public void setAccName(String accName) {
    this.accName = accName;
}

public void setAccBalance(int accBalance) {
    this.accBalance = accBalance;
}
```

}

Controller:
From controller I call Account Implement:

```
@Autowired
AccountInterface ai;

@RequestMapping(value = "/listallaccounts")
public String list(@ModelAttribute("account") AccountCommand ac, Model m) {
    ResultSet rs= ai.listAccount();
    
    if (rs != null) {
        m.addAttribute("title", "List");
        m.addAttribute("AccountList",rs);
        return ("listAccount");
    } else {
        m.addAttribute("title", "List");
        m.addAttribute("message", "No Account exist.");
        return "";
    }

}
```

DAO:
From DAO I retrieve data from database to result set.

```
AccountImplement()

public ResultSet listAccount() {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM `bankdb`.`accounts`";
    ResultSet rs = db.select(sql);
    return rs;
}
```

**My JSP:**
In this page I want show show account table.

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
         <tr>
             <th>Account Number</th>
             <th>Account Name</th>
             <th>Account balance</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <%
          request.getAttribute("AccountList");
      %>
         <c:forEach items="${AccountList}" var="item">
         <tr>
             <td>${item.AccountNumber}</td>
             <td>${item.AccountName}</td>
             <td>${item.AccountBalance}</td>
         </tr>
         </c:forEach>
   </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you should include a script then request the data from the controller using

```
 <script>
    $.ajax({
    url: "yourhost/listallaccounts",
    type: 'GET',
    data: {data});
    </script>
```

then you can format it in the table

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to notice here.

1. request.getAttribute("AccountList"); This is unnecessary as the data is in modal attribute but not in the request. So you can remove this.
2. You are setting ResultSet as data value but trying to iterate like list or collection which is not right.
3. It is not recommended to put ResultSet in modal attribute, change the ResultSet to List collection by iterating it on controller level and then set the list to modal attribute.

ResultSet to List --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/13010010/6572971

This will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly do this in jsp

```
   <%  
    AccountDAO ad;//intreface
    ad = new AccountDAOImplementation();//repository
    ResultSet rs = ad.ListAllAccount();
    
    while (rs.next()) {
%>
<tr>
    <td><% out.print(rs.getString("accountNumber")); %></td>
    <td><% out.print(rs.getString("accountName")); %></td>
    <td><% out.print(rs.getString("Balance")); %></td>
</tr>
<%
    }

%>
```

Comment: It's a very bad practice to perform java business logics inside a JSP page...too much tight coupling.